# Overriding preventDefault onclick when tab and enter are used for navigating

Tags: jquery, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a navigation with dropdown menus on larger screens, and in order to create the proper responsive behavior for smaller screens, I've set preventDefault on the parent-link that has a dropdown menu. However, if you attempt to navigate the site via the keyboard, and when you tab to a parent-link and hit enter/return, nothing happens. This is a result of the preventDefault being set on that link, even though it's being set on click.

Is there a clean way to override the preventDefault when you tab through the navigation and hit return? Ideally, I'd like to detect the focus on the parent-link when tabbing, and then display its dropdown menu, so it can be tabbed through as well.

Here's the basic jquery code for the click function...

```
$('.parent-link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // other things happen, but they're not relevant to this issue
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that by replacing the "click" event of your javascript (which includes both mouse and keyboard events) with the "mousedown" event, it will only disable the "mouse" event on the link, keeping the keyboard event clean.